# SOAP request namespace question

Tags: c#, soap, wsdl, namespaces, asmx

I require some clarification on understanding exactly what a SOAP request is asking for with respect to a .Net 3.5 ASMX web service.  Here's a sample request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/schemas/management">
<soapenv:Body>
 <spml:addRequest requestID="string" executionMode="synchronous" xmlns:spml="spmlnamespace">
  <spml:psoID ID="23099469" targetID="string" />
  <spml:data>
       <spml:attr name='groupId'>
        <spml:value>111111</spml:value>
       </spml:attr>
       <spml:attr name='mdn'>
        <spml:value>5555555555</spml:value>
       </spml:attr>
       <spml:attr name='serviceId'>
        <spml:value>SDCAT1</spml:value>
       </spml:attr>
     </spml:data>
 </spml:addRequest>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Does this mean that my asmx web service method should be named "addRequest"?  Does it also mean that this method should take two parameters, the first of type "psoID" and the second of type "data" as defined in the spml namespace?

Comment: Are you trying to reverse-engineer the WSDL?

Comment: Yeah, basically.  There's a WSDL that's provided to me, but I'm unable to generate the proxy classes using the wsdl.exe because of a bug in the tool which causes it to fail if a complex type contains a sequence of complex types.

Comment: Are you sure it is a bug in WSDL.exe and not a crap WSDL, what error do you get? Perhaps you would be better posting the section of the wsdl that wsdl.exe trips over and maybe we can work out what the problem might be.

Comment: What platform are you writing your client in. .NET?

Comment: I've edited the question to include the wsdl and imported xsd files.  I don't believe there are errors in the wsdl and xsd files, but I'm new at this.

Comment: It turns out I was able to use the wsdl.exe tool to generate the proxy classes by 1) replacing the "import" statements with "include" statements and 2) combining the first and second xsd files into one file/namespace.  Thanks for the input all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was able to use the wsdl.exe tool to generate the proxy classes by 1) replacing the "import" statements with "include" statements and 2) combining the first and second xsd files into one file/namespace. Thanks for the input all.

Comment: You should also try not editing the file, instead, pass all file paths on the command line: `wsdl.exe main.wsdl sub.wsdl main.xsd sub.xsd`